# cmake update cached variable

Tags: c++, cmake

I use a cmake variable `CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG` to specify what modules of a repo to compile, like so on command line...

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG=A ..`

This `CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG` is then used in the `CMakeLists.txt` file like so...

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG STREQUAL A)
message(STATUS "Compiling only config A modules")
set(MODULES
    foo1        
    foo2
)
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG STREQUAL B)
message(STATUS "Compiling only config B modules")
set(MODULES
    foo3
)
endif()
```

So now the first time I run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG=A ..` (or B) it works fine. After that however, it seems to have `CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG` saved in `CMakeCache.txt` and doesn't update if I call `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG=B ..`.

On searching for a solution I found the `unset(CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG CACHE)` call and added that to the end of the `CMakeLists.txt` but that doesn't do the trick.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After that however, it seems to have CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG saved in
>   CMakeCache.txt and doesn't update if I call cmake
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG=B ...

This should just work (tested with CMake 2.8.12 and higher).

Quoting the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) (emphasis mine):

> `-D <var>:<type>=<value>`, `-D <var>=<value>`
>
> Create **or update** a cmake cache entry.

You can easily verify that this works with a small test script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(cmake_tester CXX)

message("Module Config is " ${CMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG})
```

Then running cmake with different arguments for `-D` changes the cache value:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG=Foo ..
Module Config is Foo
-- Configuring done
$ cmake ..
Module Config is Foo
-- Configuring done
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_CONFIG=Bar ..
Module Config is Bar
-- Configuring done
```

If this is not working for you, it means that your build script is doing something you did not tell us about that actively prevents this from working.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution, but while there are no better solutions:

You can delete the CMakeCache.txt to prevent this problem. I suggest moving the CMakeCache.txt from the current folder, run 'cmake' and 'make', and check if it works.